# Apex: pass variable by reference

Tags: apex, method, reference

I am wondering if there is some convenient way to pass a variable to the method 'by reference', to change the actual variable in the method, not the copy of it. It would be nice to have the equivalent of C# `ref` keyword, like:

```
void m (ref int x) { }
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is to create a class and do some boxing, but it wouldn't be the prettiest solution I could imagine.

**EDIT:** I mean passing primitives of course :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think everything except primitives are passed by reference. Objects, lists, maps, etc.

How about using a list to do a poor man's equivalent?

```
void m(List<Integer> x) {
    x[0] = 4;
}

List<Integer> refs = new List<Integer>{2};

System.debug(refs[0]) //2
m(refs);
System.debug(refs[0]) //4
```

Comment: Technically, everything is passed by value. Non-primitives, however, are passed by reference-value. This means that they are effectively passed by reference, but the reason why is a bit more abstract than one might think.

Comment: That's how Java does it, too. The reference is being passed by value.  The simplest way to see it in action is to pass a reference argument to a method and then assign it the value of null inside of the method. When the method completes and you are back in the calling method the reference will not be null, because it was passed by value.

Comment: As per @sfdcfox answer, you can see [Salesforce's post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html) on pass by reference-value, and that's explained a bit more in depth [here](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

[Please check out this official documentation. I'm quoting an overview of it down here for quick reference.](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html)

> "In Apex, all primitive data type arguments, such as Integer or String, are passed into methods by value. This means that any changes to the arguments exist only within the scope of the method. When the method returns, the changes to the arguments are lost."

> "Non-primitive data type arguments, such as sObjects, are also passed into methods by value. This means that when the method returns, the passed-in argument still references the same object as before the method call, and can’t be changed to point to another object. However, the values of the object’s fields can be changed in the method."